# Dataweave transformation of converting objects with same key to array of objects

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, anypoint-studio

Below example contains same key "row". There may be thousands of such objects.
I need an optimal solution in converting below object:

```
{
    "row":{
        "name": "abc"
    },
    "row":{
        "school": "pqr"
    }
}
```

Required output:

```
{
    "rows":
    [
        {
            "name": "abc"
        },
        {
            "school": "pqr"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What is "optimal" for you exactly? You need to define the criteria to evaluate answers and decide which is more optimal.

Comment: Optimal in the sense, looking for a less expensive solution. Because around 7000 objects will be there and key for all of them as 'row'

Comment: Again, expensive in what sense? A specific metric? Any of the answers fails to meet a criteria?

Comment: The answers are perfect and works fine. Thank you for that; Could you point me to the one which will have less impact on memory and will be faster.

Comment: No. I can make a guess it is the answer using the multi-value selector because it uses only one simple operation, but to actually be sure implies performance testing in real conditions (ie similar payloads and hardware/software to what you expect in production), taking measurements of the metrics that you are interested and analyzing them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just make use of the Multi-value Selector to get all keys with same key
name:

https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dataweave-selectors

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
rows: payload.*row
```

Comment: This is the simplest solution.

Comment: It works well if all key names are row only @aled .In question its mentioned below example contains "row"

Comment: This answer works for the conditions of the question. If keys could be different it should be mentioned in the question.

Comment: All objects will have same key for eg. row in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Here groupBy will help to group similar keys and pluck will convert object to array.

- Solution 1: using mapObject(). This is a better solution since 2 plucks are eliminated here with respect to the second solution below.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
(payload groupBy $$) mapObject (($$): ($ pluck $))
```

Input

```
{
    "row":{
        "name": "abc"
    },
    "row":{
        "school": "pqr"
    }
}
```

Output

```
[
  {
    "row": [
      {
        "name": "abc"
      },
      {
        "school": "pqr"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

- Solution 2: using map()

If you want **rows** as hardcoded key then replace  `(($ pluck $$)[0]):($ pluck $)` with `("rows"):($ pluck $)`

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
(payload groupBy $$)pluck $ map{
    (($ pluck $$)[0]):($ pluck $)
}
```